# How to set a shortcut to run make in Vim and show the output

Tags: key-bindings, quickfix, ide

I'd like to run make and display the output when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> in Vim. I know how to run make and display the output while in command mode, thanks to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549828/1876983), namely with:

```
:make | copen
```

but how do I bind this to a keyboard shortcut? I managed this when I was just running make and not displaying the output namely with:

```
noremap <C-m> :make<CR>
```

in my ~/.vimrc file. Unfortunately, adding `| copen` after `:make` and before `<CR>` results in this Vim start up error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/fusion809/.vimrc:
line  157:
E488: Trailing characters:  copen <CR>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to map to a key sequence that contains `|` you have to be careful.  See [`:help map_bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map_bar).

You should probably use this mapping:

```
noremap <C-m> :make<BAR>copen<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `<Ctrl-M>` is equivalent to `<CR>`

First of all, please note that `<Ctrl-M>` is equivalent to `<CR>` which you might not use in normal mode and therefore is ok for you.
If you use the mapping, you can also press `<CR>` in normal mode to trigger make.

If you like to use a different mapping, have a look at the plugin

#### [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) by Tim Pope

This plugin provides following mappings

- <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> `:Make<CR>`
- <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> `:Make<Space>` (enter arguments)
- <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> `:Make!`
- <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> Show `'makeprg'`

and the new command `:Make` works as follows

```
                                                *dispatch-:Make*
:Make [arguments]       Using the current |:compiler| settings, dispatch a
                        build in the foreground.  Adapter strategies vary, but
                        the goal is visibility without stealing focus.  When
                        the build is complete, load the results into the
                        |quickfix| list and call |:cwindow|.  This command is
                        preferred for shorter tasks like "build this file."

:Make! [arguments]      Using the current compiler settings, dispatch a build
                        in the background.  Use |:Copen| to load the results.
                        This command is preferred for longer tasks like "run
                        the entire test suite."
```

Note the difference between `:copen` and `:cwindow`:

```
                            *:cw* *:cwindow*
:cw[indow] [height] Open the quickfix window when there are recognized
            errors.  If the window is already open and there are
            no recognized errors, close the window.

                        *:cope* *:copen* *w:quickfix_title*
:cope[n] [height]   Open a window to show the current list of errors.
```